# HttpClient authorization header not being send

Tags: yii2, authorization

I am working with an API that works well when consumed from Postman:

[image: Api Consumed from Postman]

But when I try to consume it from Yii2 I get:

> {"name":"Unauthorized","message":"Your request was made with invalid credentials.","code":0,"status":401}

and I think I am sending all the headers.

The authorization was made with a **Bearer Token**:

[image: Headers part1]

[image: Headers part2]

[image: Error]

Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just got that i have to add my headers this way:

[image]

Was adding them the wrong way.

Comment: For those who want to copy:
`$client = new Client();$response = $client->createRequest()->setMethod('POST')->setUrl($url)->setHeaders(['content-type' => 'application/json'])->addHeaders(['authorization' => 'Bearer token'])->setData(['some'=>'data'])->send();`